# Unit test with Jasmine with observable

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Angular application and I am busy with some unit test in Angular with Jasmine.

I have this piece of code:

```
 /** Gets the case by id */
    getCase(id: number, spinnerMessage?: string) {
        return this.http.get<CaseBaseModel>(`${this.api}/${id}`, spinnerMessage).pipe(map(c => new CaseBaseModel(c)));
    }
```

And I have this unit test:

```
it('should get case by id', () => {
        const spy = spyOn(service, 'getCase').and.callThrough();

        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-commented-code
         const mockData = new CaseBaseModel({
            id: 100001075,
            dateSubmitted: '',
            owner: caseOwnerEnum.caseManager,
            reference: 'ksjhkjshdf',
            status: caseStatusEnum.submitted,
            type: caseTypeEnum.revisionRequest,

        });
        service.getCase(mockData.id, 'spinner').subscribe(r => expect(r).toEqual(100001075));
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData.id, 'spinner');
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-commented-code
        // expect(mockData.id).toEqual(100001075);

});
```

But in this piece of code:

```
 /** Gets the case by id */
    getCase(id: number, spinnerMessage?: string) {
        return this.http.get<CaseBaseModel>(`${this.api}/${id}`, spinnerMessage).pipe(map(c => new CaseBaseModel(c)));
    }
```

this piece of code:

```
c => new CaseBaseModel(c)));
```

is still red.

So how to solve this?

Thank you.

This is the class CodeBaseModel:

```
export class CaseBaseModel extends CaseReferenceModel {
    id?: number;
    status: caseStatusEnum;
    substatus?: number;
    verdict?: caseVerdictEnum;
    owner: caseOwnerEnum;
    dateSubmitted: string;
    dateSubmittedFormatted?: string;
    dateClosed?: string;
    dateClosedFormatted?: string;
    comment?: string;
    comments?: CaseCommentModel[];
    sample?: boolean;
    documentList?: DocumentListModel;

    constructor(model: CaseBaseModel) {
        super(model);
    }

    getResourceForStatus?(resources, listValues: ListValueModel[]) {
        let resource: string;
        if (this.status === caseStatusEnum.inProgress) {
            const filteredListValues = listValues.filter(lv => lv.id === this.substatus);
            resource = filteredListValues.length > 0 ? filteredListValues[0].value : resources.geenZaakStatus;
        } else {
            resource = resources[enumResourcesModel[this.status]];
        }

        return resource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether you have CaseBaseModel on your code base?

Comment: Yes, I have that

Comment: I have edit the post

Comment: Where are you mocking `this.http.get()`?  You should not be making an actual http call in a unit test, so you should mock those calls.  For this simple test you could just do something like `const http = TestBed.get(HttpClient)`, then `spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(mockHttpDataResponse)`, but for more extensive http mocking, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services)

Comment: oke, thank you, for you tip